# Why can't i load the most recent tmaps package with the most recent version of terra?

Tags: terra, tmap

I am trying to load the tmap package (3.3-4) and have terra installed (1.7-3). When I try to load the tmap package, I get the following message :

> Warnung: Paket ‘tmap’ wurde unter R Version 4.2.3 erstelltError: Laden
> von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘tmap’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc,
> .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): fehlgeschlagen Namensraum
> ‘terra’ 1.7-3 ist bereits geladen, aber >= 1.7.29 wird gefordert

It says that I already have terra 1.7-3 but a version higher than 1.7-29 is required, which, to my understanding  1.7-3 is.
Any suggestion on what is the quickest way to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi there. 29 is larger than 3. At least numerically. Alphabetically it would be the other way round ;)